# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniFlyCapture2 in java.library.path

Tags: maven, netbeans, dll, jar, dependencies

I am having a link error while I run my NetBeans Project with Maven plugin.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniFlyCapture2 in java.library.path
```

In the project's pom.xml, I inserted a dependency as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
        <artifactId>flycapture</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.3.1-1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Besides, in the Project's "Dependencies" node the unfound dll file appears(see the figure below).

[image]

Strange thing is that the same Project runs well on other (original) computer where I had the same error before.  As a matter of fact, I somehow recovered from this same error on the original computer.  But I don't know how it happened.  Could anyone give me some insight?

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution. The problem was the version of JDK which is used by Netbeans. The version can be selected from the project properties as shown below. I should have been using 32bit version. Inside, 64 bit JDK was unable to call 32 bit dll.

[image]